# Unit testing service in EmberJS: How to prevent interaction between tests?

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js

I'm seeing a strange interaction when writing unit tests for services in ember.js. It only occurs on arrays.

I'm having a service which has an array as property. The state of array is shared between different tests. I don't see this behavior if property has a simple type (e.g. number). Do you have any hint what's going on?

Here is a ember-twiddle demonstrating the issue: https://ember-twiddle.com/068e0c0fd7240e54c98972002fc2e34f?openFiles=tests.unit.services.my-service-test.js%2C

Update: I noticed it works fine if I'm initialize the array in `init()` but not if I declare it as property of service object. Are complex types like array and object sharing states between different instances?

So this won't work:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Service.extend({
  array: [],
});
```

Will this is working as expected:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Service.extend({
  array: undefined,
  init() {
    this.set('array', []);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Arrays and objects defined directly on any Ember.Object are shared
>   across all instances of that object.

Section from [the guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/object-model/classes-and-instances/#toc_initializing-instances).

You need to define them in your `init` function. If you don't they share the same object.